# xUnit Test Not Passing

Tags: c#, json, serialization, xunit

I have a test method to test serialising a json object. Below is the method:

```
[Fact]
    public void Serialise_File()
    {
                    _fakeRelativeFileName = "http:\\test.com\\" + FakeFileName;
                    _fakeFileName = "Leaderboard.json"
                    _fakeJson = "[{\"Name\": \"Paddy\"}, {\"Name\": \"Dave\"}]"
                    _fakeModel = new List<MockModel>
                    {
                         new MockModel()
                         {
                             Name = "Paddy"
                         },
                         new MockModel()
                         {
                             Name = "Dave"
                         }
                    };

                    _httpContext.Server.MapPath(_fakeFileName).Returns(_fakeRelativeFileName);

        //When
        var result = _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fakeFileName, _fakeModel);

        //Then
        _file.Received(1).WriteAllText(_fakeRelativeFileName, _fakeJson);
    }
```

I get an error saying :

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException
Expected to receive exactly 1 call matching:
WriteAllText("http:\test.com\Leaderboard.json", "[{"Name": "Paddy"}, {"Name": "Dave"}]")
Actually received no matching calls.
Received 1 non-matching call (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):
WriteAllText("http:\test.com\Leaderboard.json", *"[
  {
    "Name": "Paddy"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Dave"
  }
]"*)
   at NSubstitute.Core.ReceivedCallsExceptionThrower.Throw(ICallSpecification callSpecification, IEnumerable`1 matchingCalls, IEnumerable`1 nonMatchingCalls, Quantity requiredQuantity)
   at NSubstitute.Routing.Handlers.CheckReceivedCallsHandler.Handle(ICall call)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at NSubstitute.Routing.Route.Handle(ICall call)
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleForwardingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Metro.Leaderboard.Tests.Data.JsonServiceTest.Serialise_File() in JsonServiceTest.cs: line 67
```

I don't know why it's not passing the test the json is the same for both the actual and the recieved call so, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I *think* you should escape the `"` in the string that represents the JSON

Comment: I've done that if you look at `_fakeJson`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was formatting the json file shown below:

```
var listContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
```

All I did was remove the formatting parameter `Formatting.Indented` and it passed the test!